# Assigning value to characters in text file lines in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to write a program that takes a list of names in file names.txt

The program should first alphabetize the file. Then it will take the name from the line in the file and assign a value to each character and then add up those values. For example Alan would be A = 1 L = 12 A = 1 N = 14 making the value of characters 28. I getting a "substring not found" error where I'm trying to find the sum of the letter values.

```
sum = 0 
lineNum = 1
with open('names.txt', 'r') as r :
    for line in sorted(r) :
        line = line.upper()
        for c in line :
            sum += ".ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".index(c)  <---Error here
        print(lineNum, line, sum, end='')
        lineNum += 1
```

Any tips would be appreciated. I'm wondering if the error is being caused from the file I/O aspect because it works with a program where I input names manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over the file object created by the `open` function it generates lines with trailing newline characters, so you should use the `str.rstrip` method to remove them before you process the characters in each line.

Change:

```
line = line.upper()
```

to:

```
line = line.rstrip().upper()
```

Comment: This immediately fixed that error but I had a few more bugs after that were easily figured out. I had a feeling is was going to be something as simple as a function. I was trying `line.strip()` but was getting nowhere. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple errors in your code:

Firstly, you are not gracefully handling characters that are outside of the expected values. A good way to do this would be:

```
    try:
        sum += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.index(c) + 1
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

With the line above, you don't need to add an arbitrary `.` to the beginning of the search string, and you get newline-character handling for free (no need to call `rstrip`).

Second, the `sum` value is not being reset every iteration, so all the sums are accumulated across names. Add:

```
sum = 0
```

to the top of the loop.